# Loading Informations from ArrayList on MYSQL

Tags: java

I created a `JTable` with some Tax information, so, I used Java to save this information, but some fields have been saved as `ArrayList` on MySQL. So, when i try to load this information to my `JTable`, it looks strange, with a lot of rows duplicated:

[image: JTbale Loaded]

[image: Informations On MySQLstrong text]

This is my code to load informations from MySQL:

DAO Method:

```
public PedidoCompraBeans pesquisaPedido (PedidoCompraBeans mod){
     conectaPedido.conecta();
     conectaPedido.executeSQL("Select * from compras_pedidocompra where pedidoNumero like '"+mod.getPesquisPedido()+"'");
     try{
         conectaPedido.resultset.first();

         mod.setEstabeleFatura(conectaPedido.resultset.getString("estabeleceFaturamento"));
         mod.setEnderecoFatura(conectaPedido.resultset.getString("enderecoFaturamento"));
         mod.setMunicipioFatura(conectaPedido.resultset.getString("municipioFaturamento"));
         mod.setCnpjFatura(conectaPedido.resultset.getString("cnpjfaturamento"));
         mod.setIeFatura(conectaPedido.resultset.getString("ieFaturamento"));
         mod.setEstabeleCobranca(conectaPedido.resultset.getString("estabeleceCobranca"));
         mod.setEnderecoCobranca(conectaPedido.resultset.getString("enderecoCobranca"));
         mod.setMuniciioCobranca(conectaPedido.resultset.getString("municipioCobranca"));

the rest of seach method continue.....
```

Method to send informations to JTable:

```
 public class TabelaPedido{

    public String ordemNumero;
    public String codEstoque;
    public String quantidade;
    public String tipUnidad;
    public String descricaoItem;
    public String dataPrazPedido;
    public String  precoUnit;
    public String  valorDesc;
    public String  icmsProd;
    public String  ipiissProd;
    public String  TotalSemImp;
    public String  totalComImp;
    public String  valorIcmsProd;
    public String  valorIpiIssProd;

    public TabelaPedido(){

        mod.setPesquisPedido(pesquisaPedido.getText());
        PedidoCompraBeans model = control.pesquisaPedido(mod);

        this.ordemNumero = model.getOdemNumero();
    this.codEstoque = model.getCodEstoque();
    this.quantidade = model.getQuantidade();
    this.tipUnidad = model.getUnidade();
        this.descricaoItem = model.getDescricaoItem();
    this.dataPrazPedido = model.getPrazoEntrega();
        this.precoUnit = model.getPrecoUnitario();
        this.valorDesc = model.getValorDesconto();
        this.icmsProd = model.getIcmsProduto();
        this.ipiissProd = model.getIpiissProduto();
        this.TotalSemImp = model.getTotalProdutoSemImpostos();
        this.totalComImp = model.getTotalProdutoComImpostos();
        this.valorIcmsProd = String.valueOf(model.getIcms());
        this.valorIpiIssProd = String.valueOf(model.getValorIPIISS());  
    }
}

    public ArrayList exibeItens(){      

        ArrayList<TabelaPedido> list = new ArrayList<TabelaPedido>();

        TabelaPedido item1 = new TabelaPedido();
        TabelaPedido item2 = new TabelaPedido();
        TabelaPedido item3 = new TabelaPedido();
        TabelaPedido item4 = new TabelaPedido();
        TabelaPedido item5 = new TabelaPedido();
        TabelaPedido item6 = new TabelaPedido();
        TabelaPedido item7 = new TabelaPedido();
        TabelaPedido item8 = new TabelaPedido();
        TabelaPedido item9 = new TabelaPedido();
        TabelaPedido item10 = new TabelaPedido();
        TabelaPedido item11 = new TabelaPedido();
        TabelaPedido item12 = new TabelaPedido();
        TabelaPedido item13 = new TabelaPedido();
        TabelaPedido item14 = new TabelaPedido();

        list.add(item1);
        list.add(item2);
        list.add(item3);
        list.add(item4);
        list.add(item5);
        list.add(item6);
        list.add(item7);
        list.add(item8);
        list.add(item9);
        list.add(item10);
        list.add(item11);
        list.add(item12);
        list.add(item13);
        list.add(item14);
        return list;
    }

    public void adicionaItensTabela(){

        DefaultTableModel mode = (DefaultTableModel) tabelProduto.getModel();
        ArrayList<TabelaPedido> list = exibeItens();
        Object rowData[] = new Object[14];

        for(int a = 0; a < list.size(); a++){

                rowData[0] = list.get(a).ordemNumero;
                rowData[1] = list.get(a).codEstoque;
                rowData[2] = list.get(a).quantidade;
                rowData[3] = list.get(a).tipUnidad;
                rowData[4] = list.get(a).descricaoItem;
                rowData[5] = list.get(a).dataPrazPedido;
                rowData[6] = list.get(a).precoUnit;
                rowData[7] = list.get(a).valorDesc;
                rowData[8] = list.get(a).icmsProd;
                rowData[9] = list.get(a).ipiissProd;
                rowData[10] = list.get(a).TotalSemImp;
                rowData[11] = list.get(a).totalComImp;
                rowData[12] = list.get(a).valorIcmsProd;
                rowData[13] = list.get(a).valorIpiIssProd;

        mode.addRow(rowData);
    }
}
```

What have i mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

In `pesquisaPedido` you execute your sql query but it looks you only read the first row from the result set and returns it. Since the exact same query most likely will always return the rows in the same order this method will always return the exact same row of data

This mean each call to the constructor `TabelaPedido()` will create exactly the same element for your `ArrayList`.

The solution here is first that `pesquisaPedido` should return all rows from the sql query in a list and that when creating `TabelaPedido` objects you should do so by iterating over that list. The constructor should take a `PedidoCompraBeans` as an argument so that you do the looping outside.

`exibeItens`, I don’t really understand this method. Is it always 14 rows in the database table?